# Mini Cart in Magento not updating float quantities

Tags: php, magento, floor

I am having a problem with the minicart on my Magento e commerce website.

Many of the products (though not all) can accept decimal values for their quantity.

For example here : https://www.greenveggy.com/vegetables/potato/potato.html

It also shows up properly when you click on the "Cart" link in the top right corner.

However, if you try to update the qty there itself (in the dropdown cart that you see when you click the cart link), it will not accept decimal values. It will pick the floor values each time, so 2.5 will become 2.

Can anyone point me to the problem here?

Comment: Can you post some code and some things that you have tried already?

Comment: The only thing I could think of was to got to the backend and check the setting "Qty Uses Decimals". It was set to yes.

I couldn't think of anything else, since all the code is of Magento.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/minicart.js** on line 133:

```
var quantity = parseInt(input.val(), 10);
```

`parseInt` function returns only integer values. If you want to support float numbers, you should copy this file to your theme and change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`.